# Как сделать запрос через тэг <a> laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть кнопки-ссылки для сортировки товаров по цене. При нажатии на ссылку нужно передать в url параметры сортировки. Обработку параметров из url я сделал и проверил вручную вбив в адресную строку параметры.

Как передать параметры через `<a>` также как через `<form>` ?

Важно чтобы передаваемы параметры не заменяли другие параметры, а только свои. Т.е. если есть `?brand=Apple`, то после нажатия на `<a>` будет `?brand=Apple&sort=priceDesc`. И ещё чтобы не было дублирования при повторном нажатии на `<a>` т.е. чтобы не было `?brand=Apple&sort=priceDesc&sort=priceDesc&sort=priceDesc&sort=priceDesc&sort=priceDesc`

Comment: `src="{{http_build_query($_GET) . '&sort=-price'}}"`

Comment: @InDevX Спасибо. Это работает. А если на странице, есть форма, помимо тегов `<a>` вне формы, которая отправляет данные через get, то в этом случае как быть? Ведь отправка через форму заменит указанные мной в url `&sort=-price`, а хотелось бы это сохранить.

Comment: Или это нереально адекватно сделать без JS с запросами AJAX?

Comment: Да, без js это адекватно не сделать. В идеале все фильтры на js (или даже ajax) перенести